# android camera and gallery not working in nexus 5

Tags: android, android-camera, android-gallery, android-4.4-kitkat, android-camera-intent

In my application I use camera and gallery to upload the selected image to server. it's working fine till 4.4.2, but in 4.4.4 nexus5 both camera and gallery don't work. **my camera part is in a Fragment**.If I try to take a photo using the camera or pick a photo using the gallery I get "please retry" message as per my code.

camera action code:

```
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/appname";
        File photopath = new File(path);
        if (!photopath.exists()) {
            photopath.mkdir();
        }

        try {
            Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                    MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support capturing images!";
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
```

......

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        Log.e("request code", "" + requestCode);
        Log.e("result code", "" + resultCode);
        Log.e("Activity.RESULT_OK", "" + getActivity().RESULT_OK);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please retry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

what is the problem behind the 4.4.4 version? or is it my mistake? How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Have you get any solution for that? Because I am facing same problem

Comment: I show the last taken image using media provider. i am make sure my code capture the image and show the last taken image.